# SugarCRM 8.0.1 not recognizing increase in limit of total fields in Elasticsearch 5.6.9 index

Tags: json, elasticsearch, sugarcrm, elasticsearch-5

In SugarCRM 8.0.1, I am trying to schedule a full system index, but I am running into the following error in the SugarCRM error log:

```
[FATAL] Elasticsearch request failure: Limit of total fields [1000] in index [my_index] has been exceeded
```

I am connected to a service running Elasticsearch 5.6.9 on another machine. There, I ran the following command to increase the service's field limit:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000
}
'
```

I know that this command is sticking because in return after running it I get this:

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

And if I run the following...

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings?pretty'`

...this is part of what is returned:

```
"my_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "total_fields" : {
            "limit" : "10000"
          },
```

**All looks well, but I am still getting the same error back in my SugarCRM error log after trying to run the full system index again.**

Are there any steps I am missing to make sure SugarCRM recognizes the new field limit? I have tried running a quick repair & rebuild and refreshing my cache in Sugar, but to no avail.

I also know that restarting my Elasticsearch service is no use because the PUT request I am running to increase the new field limit is only for the currently running service; if I restart it, I'd have to put in the PUT request again, so that would be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not just the setting getting lost when Sugar recreates the index?

I'd give this a go in `config_override.php`:

```
 $sugar_config['full_text_engine']['Elastic']['index_settings']['default']['index.mapping.total_fields.limit'] = 10000;
```

I'm not quite sure that's the right way to phrase the option though.

Inspired by https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Installation_Upgrade/Installing_and_Administering_Elasticsearch/#Advanced_Index_Settings

Comment: Your phrasing was perfect and this fixes my issue completely; thank you! Adding that line to `config_override.php` is a much better way to handle this rather than using the REST API because now the setting won't get lost every time the Elasticsearch service is restarted.